# What are the possible types of intrusions that a IDS protects against?

Tags: network, attacks, ids, intrusion

I am implementing an IDS and just want to know that what are the possibilities with which the intrusion can occur. I am just doing a literature survey over the attacks possible so I want to know that what are the types of intrusions possible in host that can compromise the security of the system which can help make me the system better.

Comment: Every service the host offers, offers also an opportunity worth checking for exploitation. Buffer overflows, local access, remote access, misconfigured policies that allow stuff that is not supposed to, policy exceptions, implementation that does not follow the desired specification design, ...

Comment: In practice, if your IDS does not have some sort of facility for detecting *unusual activity*, it will be nearly worthless.  If you knew in advance the specifics of what an intrusion usually looks like, as a responsible system administration you would have patched the vulnerability long before any intruders appeared.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a [few thousand CWEs](http://cwe.mitre.org/data/slices/2000.html) used to classify [tens of thousands of vulnerabilities](http://web.nvd.nist.gov/view/vuln/statistics-results?cves=on&query=&cwe_id=&pub_date_start_month=-1&pub_date_start_year=-1&pub_date_end_month=-1&pub_date_end_year=-1&mod_date_start_month=-1&mod_date_start_year=-1&mod_date_end_month=-1&mod_date_end_year=-1&cvss_sev_base=&cvss_av=&cvss_ac=&cvss_au=&cvss_c=&cvss_i=&cvss_a=).  That should come pretty close to addressing this problem.

Oah and don't forget about application/protocol specific encoding.   That is the bread and butter of IDS/IPS bypass.